# Complex JUnit test Case

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a test case using JUnit for a method that takes an `ENUM` in the switch statement. 
This is the method to be tested.

```
public <T extends BaseServiceResponse> T postProcess(T response,
        ClientResponse clientResponse) throws EISClientException {  

    List<Message> messages = response.getMessages();
    if(messages==null || messages.size()==0) {
        return response;
    }

    Map<String, Message> messagesMap = populateMessages(response.getMessages());
    ConditionOperator condition = getCondition();

    switch(condition) {
        case OR:
            checkORCondition( messagesMap );
            break;
        case AND:
            checkANDCondition( messagesMap );
            break;
    }       
    return response;
}
```

What I've done so far is:

```
@Test
public void testPostProcess() throws Exception {
    clientResponse = mock(ClientResponse.class);

    RetrieveBillingServiceResponse response = new RetrieveBillingServiceResponse();
    BillingOverview billingOverView = new BillingOverview();

    Message message = new Message();
    message.setMessageCode("200");
    message.setMessageType(MessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_INFO);
    message.setMessageText("Service completed successfully");

    response.setEntity(billingOverView);
    response.setMessages(Arrays.asList(message));

    MessageToExceptionPostProcessFilter postProcessFilter = new MessageToExceptionPostProcessFilter();
    RetrieveBillingServiceResponse serviceResponse = postProcessFilter.postProcess(response, clientResponse);

    assertEquals("200", serviceResponse.getMessages().get(0).getMessageCode());
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` for conditonOperator which is of type `ENUM` and this holds only two members `OR` and `AND` which are the cases in the `switch` statement.
Can someone help me out how should I proceed with this test.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to show what `getCondition();` returns. You should be able to isolate the problem quite easily by stepping through your code line-by-line with a debugger.

Comment: getCondition() returns object of type ConditionOperator which is an `ENUM`

Answer (score 1):

Enum variables can be null. The `getCondition()` method is returning null. Why it's returning null, we can't really guess without seeing code you haven't shown us.

Comment: getCondition() returns object of type ConditionOperator which is an `ENUM`. 

public ConditionOperator getCondition() {
  return condition;
 }

Answer (score 0):

If getCondition() is private method you cannot mock it. If it is public method, you can mock it or if you have a setCondition, you can directly set the ENUM.

Assuming if you are using Mockito or PowerMock or EasyMock you can use something like

```
when(postProcessFilter.getCondition()).thenReturn(Enum.OR);
```

Comment: Thank you all, I got it how to set the conditonOperator using setter.